# Sending a rendered report from the controller to a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, report

So I was doing some research into this and from what I can gather, the technology that used to do this has been phased out.

I have an RDLC file. I am trying to use the LocalReport class but it seems that the view severely dislikes receiving a rendered report. I am using MVC5.

Would anyone be able to recommend something I could look at as an alternative to using the LocalReport class or RDLC files. Or would anyone be able to provide some insight on how to do this correctly.

Please let me know if you would like to have a look at some of the code I am using.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well, I managed to get around my issue like this:

I created the report and saved it to a temporary folder which gets deleted every day.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/TempReports/report.pdf"), renderedBytes);
```

My Controller action just returned a link to the rendered report.

JavaScript:

```
function GenerateReport() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Reporting/ReportAction",
            data: { param1: "", param2: "" },
            success: function (data) {
                var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
                if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
                    //set of functions specific to IE
                    var success = new PDFObject({ url: data }).embed("reportGenIe");
                    $("#reportGenIe").attr('hidden', false);
                }
                else {
                    //Normal browsers
                    var success = new PDFObject({ url: data }).embed("reportGen");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Unable to generate the report.");
            }
        });
```

For IE I used an Iframe and for other browsers I used an Object

```
<div role="content" style="padding-bottom:20px; height:650px !important">
    <iframe id="reportGenIe" hidden="hidden"></iframe>
    <object id="reportGen"></object>
</div>
```

This includes getting around IE refusing to display a pdf dynamically for me.

I used the PDFObject js library which seems to have done the trick.
http://pdfobject.com/